Is there a study of Quadratic Transformations?
In Linear algebras I remember learning about linear transformations, with examples being integrals and derivatives. The basic definition I remember is that $f(x)$ is a linear transformation if $f(a +b) = f(a) + f(b)$ and that $f(ax) = af(x)$.
What I have often wondered is there a quadratic version of these. I'm not exactly sure how it'd look maybe $f(a + b) = f^2(a) + f^2(b)$ or maybe it'd be $f(a + b) = f^2(a) +f(ab) + f^2(b)$ and $f(ax) = a^2f(x)$.
I am curious if these types of transformations are studied, do they have uses, and if studied what are some good examples of some of these transformations.
Thank you!

Sounds kind of like quadratic forms - these (and the closely related bilinear forms) appear everywhere.

I think this question is related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/248532/870236

https://planetmath.org/quadraticspace

We could take $f(x)=x\odot x$, where $\odot$ is a vector-valued bilinear form, i.e. the multiplication in an algebra.

I did look at both quadratic forms and the other article mentioned. Another way to ask my question is are there quadratic transformation, cubic transformations, etc. Are those things defined and studied?
